# Android Yandex maps kit - зависание

Tags: android, многопоточность, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

После работы с картами в течении какого-то времени приложение зависает, причем делает это весьма странно.
Перестают работать транзакции фрагментов, notifydatasetchanged ничего не делает ни на каком адаптере, запуски Activity тоже (при это никаких exception'ов не происходит, все эти методы вызываются и просто в итоге ничего не происходит).
Карта тоже зависает и больше не реагирует на нажатия. Если переключиться с яндекса на гугл карту - то никаких зависаний нет, все хорошо.

В то же время я могу скрывать и показывать вьюшки программно, делать сетевые запросы, у всех UI-элементов срабатывают анимации нажатия и т.д.

Магия какая-то, в общем. Буду благодарен за хоть какую-либо наводку, т.к. я понятия не имею в какую сторону еще смотреть.
Видимо какой-то особый поток застрял, который отрабатывает активности, фрагменты, адаптеры?

Comment: попробуйте перейти на новую версию MapKit: tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapkit это должно помочь

Comment: @Reni здравствуйте, вопрос старый, проблема тогда решилась. Возможно Вам имеет смысл добавить в джавадок, что коллбек от карт приходит в негуевом треде :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что проблема была в том, что из коллбека карт (не помню уже названия) происходила работа с UI, в то время как он работал не в main потоке.

Поиск проблема осложнился тем, что приложение не падало и UI даже реагировал периодически (возможно коллбек иногда приходит из main, а иногда нет?) и только по прошествии какого-то времени все зависало :)